# PangoCairo shows cluttered text when cairo context is scaled

Tags: c, pangocairo

I'm playing around with PangoCairo and found out that if the cairo context is scaled, pango draws letters closer together when scale is less than 1 and spaced from each other when scale is more than one.

Here is the minimum example (I've took it from https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Cairo-Rendering.html PangoCairo documentation and just added scale)

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <pango/pangocairo.h>

static void
draw_text (cairo_t *cr)
{
#define RADIUS 150
#define N_WORDS 10
#define FONT "Sans Bold 27"
#define SCALE .5

  PangoLayout *layout;
  PangoFontDescription *desc;
  int i;

  /* Center coordinates on the middle of the region we are drawing
   */
  cairo_translate (cr, RADIUS, RADIUS);

  /* Create a PangoLayout, set the font and text */
  layout = pango_cairo_create_layout (cr);

  pango_layout_set_text (layout, "Text", -1);
  desc = pango_font_description_from_string (FONT);
  pango_layout_set_font_description (layout, desc);
  pango_font_description_free (desc);

  /* Draw the layout N_WORDS times in a circle */
  for (i = 0; i < N_WORDS; i++)
    {
      int width, height;
      double angle = (360. * i) / N_WORDS;
      double red;

      cairo_save (cr);

      /* Gradient from red at angle == 60 to blue at angle == 240 */
      red   = (1 + cos ((angle - 60) * G_PI / 180.)) / 2;
      cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, red, 0, 1.0 - red);

      cairo_rotate (cr, angle * G_PI / 180.);

      /* Inform Pango to re-layout the text with the new transformation */
      pango_cairo_update_layout (cr, layout);

      pango_layout_get_size (layout, &width, &height);
      cairo_move_to (cr, - ((double)width / PANGO_SCALE) / 2, - RADIUS);
      pango_cairo_show_layout (cr, layout);

      cairo_restore (cr);
    }

  /* free the layout object */
  g_object_unref (layout);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  cairo_t *cr;
  char *filename;
  cairo_status_t status;
  cairo_surface_t *surface;

  if (argc != 2)
    {
      g_printerr ("Usage: cairosimple OUTPUT_FILENAME\n");
      return 1;
    }

     filename = argv[1];

  surface = cairo_image_surface_create (CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32,
                                        2 * RADIUS * SCALE, 2 * RADIUS * SCALE);
  cr = cairo_create (surface);

  cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  cairo_paint (cr);
  cairo_scale(cr, SCALE, SCALE);
  draw_text (cr);
  cairo_destroy (cr);

  status = cairo_surface_write_to_png (surface, filename);
  cairo_surface_destroy (surface);

  if (status != CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
      g_printerr ("Could not save png to '%s'\n", filename);
      return 1;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Here how the rendered text looks like when there are no modification to the tutorial source or `SCALE` is set to 1:

[image: At scale 1.0]

With `SCALE` 0.5:

[image: At scale 0.5]

And with `SCALE` 1.5:

[image: At scale 1.5]

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but googling doesn't help many.

Comment: Without rotations the behaviour is the same.

Comment: I get the same behaviour if I apply the Cairo transformations before the Pango context is created (or updated). However the text is output correctly if the transformations are applied after. I used a trick to save, reset the matrix, create/update the Pango layout, then set the matrix again.